# Add a Yammer group functionality to an existing Office 365 group

Tags: office365, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

It appears that "groups" within Office 365 do not all have the same capabilities.

I want to create a group with all the major features:

- Teams
- Sharepoint
- Calendar
- Email
- Yammer

Creating a group in Teams only do not create the other items.

Creating a group in Outlook (New Outlook web version in my case) will create a Sharepoint/Calendar/Email group; and then it is possible to create a team in Teams based on that group.

**So the question is**: how can I then add a Yammer functionality to this?

If I create a Yammer group, I'll have Yammer + Sharepoint but it won't be a Outlook group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using your environment, but the documentation seems clear enough on
the procedure:

1. Connect Yammer to your Office 365 identity
2. Creating a new Yammer group will give it access to Office 365.

The article
[What is Yammer and why you need it](https://sharepointmaven.com/what-is-yammer-and-why-you-need-it/)
from July 18, 2018,
contains a detailed description with screenshots in the section
*Integration with Office 365 Groups*:

1. In Yammer, click on *Gear Icon > Network Admin*
2. Under *Content and Security*, click on *Security Settings*
3. Under *Office 365 Identity Enforcement*, click *Enforce Office 365 identity*
4. On the next screen, make sure to select *Committed* option (not 7-day trial)
5. Click *Save*.

The article also says:

> **What will happen once you connect Yammer with Office 365 Groups**
>
> 1. When you create a new Yammer Group, it will also provision an Office 365 Group with all the assets you would typically expect in
>      Office 365 Group (SharePoint site collection, Planner, OneNote).
> 2. On the new Yammer Group page, you will notice Office 365 Group resources accessible on the right-side panel. Clicking on each will
>      bring you to the corresponding Office 365 Group asset.

The article maintains that Yammer groups are incompatible with Outlook,
but this conflicts with Microsoft's documentation (which is more recent).

Microsoft's article
[Yammer and Office 365 Groups](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/yammer/manage-yammer-groups/yammer-and-office-365-groups)
from February 2019 says:

> **What happens when you create a new Office 365 connected Yammer group**
>
> When you create an Office 365 connected group from Yammer, in addition
>   to your regular Yammer group features, the new Office 365 group is
>   created, and a new SharePoint site and document library, OneNote
>   notebook, and Planner are created for the group. These resources can
>   be accessed from the Yammer group page in Yammer.

The article also says:

> **Email and Office 365 connected groups**
>
> In a connected group set up from Yammer, you can have group
>   conversations in Yammer or in Outlook. You can send an email to a
>   group in Yammer and it will appear in the group's Yammer messages, or
>   use the group's name from the Outlook global address list (GAL) to
>   send email to the group that goes directly to Outlook.
>
> Your company can continue to use groups in Yammer and groups in
>   Outlook based on which group type better fits the scenario for a team.
>
> Email notifications for Yammer messages may be sent to users depending
>   on the preferences that they have set in their Yammer notification
>   settings. This applies both to connected and non-connected groups.

I hope that this information can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I basically agree with all this but I have to test again (create a group in yammer, see that I can use it as a full Outlook group, then create a Teams team based on that outlook group). I'll update.

Comment: And thanks for the summarising all this by the way.

Comment: When creating a group in Yammer, it will become a "Office 365 connected group" (which I understand is also a Outlook group, but that's not sure) only if "List this group in our network's group directory and search results." is selected, if not then the shared ressources are not created (in case the group is private).

Comment: Then I don't see it in my Outlook groups, but if I try "discover groups" then I can see it listed, with ... myself as a member. But I don't seem to be able to join. In addition, when trying to create a Teams team based on a existing Outlook group, I don't see it listed.

Comment: You are using new software that might not yet be up to the task. Perhaps you should address the question to the [developers](https://developer.yammer.com/feedback/bug). We cannot here fix bugs in the software.

Comment: Sure, I understand that, wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something, and this question can serve a reference for when they hopefully make it work.

Comment: See this: https://yammer.uservoice.com/forums/399627-yammer/suggestions/37186639-group-integration-with-o365-outlook-and-teams